# Rename multiple files name in CMD

Tags: cmd

Every of my files have the same month which I would like to replace.

The problem is the month is in the middle and after a space. It looks something like this `apple Oct'18.xlsx`

Base on this website, 
https://superuser.com/questions/475874/how-does-the-windows-rename-command-interpret-wildcards

I tried to use `ren ??????Oct???*.xlsx ??????Nov???*.xlsx`

Comment: whenever you have files / paths with spaces, use quotes: `ren "??????Oct???*.xlsx" "??????Nov???*.xlsx"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> missing in your file pattern. You can use the following command line...:

```cmd
ren "* Oct'*.xlsx" "* Nov'*.*"
```

..., given that the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> before the month name is the last one in the file names.

Hence using that command line, the following files:

> ```cmd
> and some pears Oct'18_xyz.xlsx
> apples Oct'18.xlsx
> bananas Oct'18.xlsx
> more fruit Oct'18_xyz.xlsx
> oranges Oct'18.xlsx
> plus peaches Oct'18_xyz.xlsx
> strawberries Oct'18 abcdef.xlsx
> ```

...become renamed to these ones:

> ```cmd
> and some pears Nov'18_xyz.xlsx
> apples Nov'18.xlsx
> bananas Nov'18.xlsx
> more fruit Nov'18_xyz.xlsx
> oranges Nov'18.xlsx
> plus peaches Nov'18_xyz.xlsx
> strawberries Oct'18 Nov'ef.xlsx
> ```

As you can see, the last file has been renamed wrongly, since it violates the aforementioned restriction concerning <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> behind the month name.

Comment: Can check with you. When I tried to used back the same code. 
It change my file exactly like your strawberries Oct'18 abc.xlsx example above. 
Where the month did not change but the one before the file extension changed.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy using PowerShell as a tool with the `-replace` operator

```
Powershell -NoP -C "Dir '* Oct*.xlsx'|Ren -NewName {$_.Name -Replace ' Oct',' Nov'}
```

Sample outout lending aschipfl's template

```
and some pears Nov'18_xyz.xlsx
apples Nov'18.xlsx
bananas Nov'18.xlsx
more fruit Nov'18_xyz.xlsx
oranges Oct'18.xls2x
plus peaches Nov'18_xyz.xlsx
strawberries Nov'18 abc.xlsx
```