# Replace string with another string

Tags: replace, cmd, rename

I would like to replace the current month to another month while everything else stay the same.
I have hundred over files which I thought of using rename function in CMD.

My file before is `apple Oct'18 banana.xlsx`, I want change is it to `'apple Nov'18 banana.xlsx'`

The closest I gotten was using `Ren *oct*.xlsx "* Nov'18 banana*".xlsx`
but the result I got in return was `apple Oct Nov banana.xlsx`

However, I cannot replace the Oct completely.

Comment: Does [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/228733/how-to-rename-multiple-files-by-replacing-word-in-file-name) help ?

Comment: Oh, this reminds me of this question: [Rename multiple files name in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53514500). I think it is not possible with just the `ren` command, I believe you have to do some explicit string manipulation...

Answer (score 2):

Try `ren *.xlsx ??????Nov??????????.*`

`*` is a wildcard to match every ".xlsx" extension.

`?` is a wildcard to make every character in the original file stay unchanged.

Comment: I tried it on this file apple oct banana.xlsx, it did work but when I tried on my other files, it doesn't. They have different number of characters in front.

Comment: @chee-seng-ng Check out this answer I found at [link](https://superuser.com/questions/236820/how-do-i-remove-the-same-part-of-a-file-name-for-many-files-in-windows-7) it might help as well.

Comment: @cheesengng said that ONLY one file must be renamed. Here, you rename all `xlsx` files.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no way to accomplish your task by a single `ren` command line.

You could write a batch file with the following code and name it `ren_date.bat`:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=."   & rem // (root directory; `.` is current, `%~dp0.` is parent)
set "_FROM=%~1" & rem // (name portion to be replaced; `%~1` is 1st argument)
set "_TO=%~2"   & rem // (name portion to be inserted; `%~2` is 2st argument)

rem // Enumerate all matching files (note the SPACE behind the asterisk):
for /F "delims=| eol=|" %%J in ('dir /B /A:-D "%_ROOT%\* %_FROM%*.xlsx"') do (
    rem // Store current file name, initialise variable for new name:
    set "FILE=%%J" & set "NAME="
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of exclamation marks:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Replace each SPACE in current file name by `" "` and enclose the
    rem    whole string in between `""`, so we get a list of quoted items,
    rem    which reflect all the SPACE-separated file name parts: */
    for %%I in ("!FILE: =" "!") do (
        endlocal
        rem // Store current file name part:
        set "PART=%%~I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* Assemble new name, performing the intended substitution of the
        rem    predefined sub-strings; the `for /F` loop is needed to transport
        rem    the resulting new file name over the `endlocal` barrier: */
        for /F "delims=| eol=|" %%K in ("!NAME! !PART:%_FROM%=%_TO%!") do (
            endlocal
            rem // Store the assembled name portion:
            set "NAME=%%K"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
    )
    rem // Now rename file to the assembled new name:
    ren "!_ROOT!\!FILE!" "!NAME:~1!"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Then run it in `cmd` using the following command lines, given that you are in the directory that contains the files to rename:

```cmd
ren_date.bat "Oct'18" "Nov'18"
```

Referring to the example from [my answer to a former question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53517255), this should rename the files:

> ```cmd
> and some pears Oct'18_xyz.xlsx
> apples Oct'18.xlsx
> bananas Oct'18.xlsx
> more fruit Oct'18_xyz.xlsx
> oranges Oct'18.xlsx
> plus peaches Oct'18_xyz.xlsx
> strawberries Oct'18 abcdef.xlsx
> ```

To these ones:

> ```cmd
> and some pears Nov'18_xyz.xlsx
> apples Nov'18.xlsx
> bananas Nov'18.xlsx
> more fruit Nov'18_xyz.xlsx
> oranges Nov'18.xlsx
> plus peaches Nov'18_xyz.xlsx
> strawberries Nov'18 abcdef.xlsx
> ```

(To write the above code into a command line directly in `cmd` is not possible, I believe, particularly due to the toggling of delayed expansion to make the code safe.)

Answer (score 0):

As batch only knows the variable type string ad isn't good at date time calculations,
I suggest to use PowerShell for this.

With the

- [datetime] type and
- the `.AddMonths()` method
- the Regular expression based `-match` operator

it will do even crossing year boundaries:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\12\13\SO_53757192.ps1
$CI = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture
$dt = ' MMM\''yy '
Get-ChildItem '* ???''[0-9][0-9] *.xlsx' |
  Where-Object BaseName -match ' (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)''(\d{2}) ' |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $Matches[0],
      [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[0],$dt,$CI).AddMonths(1).ToString($dt)} # -WhatIf
```

You can invoke it from batch as a file

```
powershell -NoP -Ex bypass -File ".\SO_53757192.ps1"
```

Or cram it into one line

```
powershell -NoP -C "$CI=[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture;$dt=' MMM\''yy ';Get-ChildItem '* ???''[0-9][0-9] *.xlsx'|Where-Object BaseName -match ' (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)''(\d{2}) '|Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $Matches[0],[datetime]::ParseExact($matches[0],$dt,$CI).AddMonths(1).ToString($dt)}"
```